# Will my submission be rejected if I accidentally submit the non-blind version to a conference with double blind review?

Tags: conference, peer-review, anonymity

I recently submitted a paper for a conference, I'm pretty confident about the topic and contents of the paper, but I just realized I sent the copy where the authors' names are in it, i.e. not the "blind" version that the conference requires. And I realized this a few days from the notification due date, which is today. I cannot change my submission from EasyChair.

Do you think this will get me rejected? And what should I do now? Should I e-mail the organizer and send them the blind copy?

Comment: What's wrong with submitting a paper containing author names? Isn't that the standard way of submitting a paper?

Comment: @eykanal, not when double-blind review is required.

Comment: @jeff: I'm curious to know what was the result at the end? was it rejected due to the above issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might get rejected without review. I would write the Program Chair now, explain your accidental submission of the wrong version of the manuscript, and ask for permission to resubmit the correct version.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did now. So I guess I'm in the hands of the PC.

Comment: They told me that "it is not necessary for now", I'm not sure whether it means "it's too late now" or "it is OK" . Now I'm in the hands of the reviewers :) So, would you reject an article just because of this?

Comment: @halilpazarlama That sounds that it is OK and will be reviewed normally.

Comment: I would and have reported non-blinded submissions to the Program Chair or sub-chair for my area and let them deal with the issue. The goal of blind submission is to prevent bias, even unconscious bias, against under-represented groups which can be discovered through the names of the submitters. It's up to the PC how much they want to pursue this goal.

Comment: @BillBarth that makes sense, and relieves me a bit, also Vladimir's answer. Thanks !

Comment: @BillBarth: That is certainly not the main reason, or the original reason, that blind submission exists.

Comment: @TomChurch, my [understanding](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/mckinley/notes/blind.html) is different from yours. Perhaps you can link to some references that give the original and current reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

This is dependent on the conference.  I just reviewed papers for a conference last week in which the reviewers were instructed to notify chairs of any revealing information of the author.  When I opened the file I noticed the names, although I had not known who it was.  I contacted the chair and they worked with the author on resubmitting.  I did not know who they were, so I reviewed the paper anyway at the will of the chair.  From your comments, it seems something similar may have happened.  The best is to email as soon as you realize your mistake, but it is not always a strict reject.